# React: Find out if an element is inside another ref container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var myContainer: any = null;

<div id="container" ref={container => myContainer = container}>
 <p id="child" > test</p>
</div>
```

Now i would like to know that if the event.target is inside ref.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

      var target = event.target;

      if(target is inside myContainer){
        console.log("target is inside my container");
      }


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the target is inside the wrapper using `contains`. 
Try something like this

```
  document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      var target = event.target;
      if(this.myContainer && this.myContainer.contains(target)){
        console.log("target is inside my container");
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good asnwer here:

https://codepen.io/blustemy/pen/QdjXaO

Basically you can replace this line

```
document.getElementById("flyout-example");
```

with the ref aka

'myContainer'

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains() which returns boolean indicating whether a node is a descendant of a specified node. Check example below

```
var span = document.getElementById("mySPAN");
var div = document.getElementById("myDIV").contains(span);
```